# How to add vendor shared lib to android ndk app

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-source, ndk-build

I have added a library under Android aosp vendor folder and successfully created shared lib (lets say, libmyvendor.so) files. And verified that .so files are created under both `system/lib` and `system/lib64`. Flashed on a device and working fine here.

To debug my ndk application, I have copied .so files into Android's path sdk/ndk/{versionNumber}/platforms/android-28/arch-x86/usr/lib. Also in archx86_64/usr/lib64 folder. Did invalidate and restart Android Studio. Now I'm trying to find or add libmyvendor library in my ndk application using cmake function

```
find_library(mVendor libmyvendor)
```

Tried *myvendor* instead of *libmyvendor*. In both cases, cmake couldn't find it.

Then tried copying libmyvendor.so files into ndk application (under jniLibs/x86/ and x86_64/ ). Compiled  but app crash at runtime saying

```
UnSatifiedLinkError: dlopen failed library 'libcrypto.so' not found
```

Where libcrypto.so is needed as a dependent to libmyvendor project. And I'm stuck here.

As per my assumption, libmyvendor is part of system libs. NDK should be capable of finding it using `find_library()`, just like we find liblog.so. But it cannot find. Did I miss or mess anything?

Comment: `libmyvendor.so` is created by you? not then from where you find it

Comment: try `find_library(mVendor myvendor)` this, remove `lib` prefix to find

Comment: yes, `libmyvendor.so` is created by me as part of aosp build.

Comment: are you using CMake?

Comment: yes, using CMake

Comment: the error says about `libcrypto.so`, can you find this file both on the device and your toolchain?

Comment: yes, it is there along with `libmyvendor.so` file